# Please rename tag JSF-2.0 to JSF-2

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, retag-request

Please rename [jsf-2.0](/questions/tagged/jsf-2.0) to [jsf-2](/questions/tagged/jsf-2). It's already one of its synonyms. This was ever requested by a moderator flag, but it was declined with the suggestion to bring it to meta.

Renaming the tag to a major version specific one is better than creating new tags for the new minor versions [jsf-2.1](/questions/tagged/jsf-2.1) and the shortly upcoming [jsf-2.2](/questions/tagged/jsf-2.2) (and [jsf-2.3](/questions/tagged/jsf-2.3), etc) as the technical differences are merely in the area of spec enhancements. The difference between JSF 1.x and 2.x is too big (it's basically a major spec change) to merge [jsf-2.0](/questions/tagged/jsf-2.0) immediately with [jsf](/questions/tagged/jsf).

As a side-remark, I personally don't find [jsf-1.2](/questions/tagged/jsf-1.2) useful, it can as good be merged with [jsf](/questions/tagged/jsf).

Note: the guy below my cap is the top user in those tags, so I know what I am talking about.

Comment: So it wasn't the deaf guy answering JSF questions on SO either?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have renamed jsf-2.0 to jsf-2 and merged the two.  Enjoy!

Comment: W00t, thanks! But does it require some postprocessing time or what? Some things seem to be still hanging on the old tag. Right now when I want to go to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsf-2, it redirects to tagged/jsf-2.0 and I don't see the tag wiki excerpt. Also, the tag badges are still on jsf-2.0.

Comment: It should be working now.